# button should show when value is set to true but it is not

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When i set the value to true under the object canPurchase the add to cart button should show. for some reason i can only get it to show when i set ng-show with an exclamation in front of it.
i am still new to angular so i dont know the terminology very well.

here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jL0c6sLc/

```
    <body class="container"  ng-app="gemStore">
       <div class="product row">
         <h1>Store Name</h1>
       </div>
       <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <div class="product row" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
          <h3>{{product.name}}<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em></h3>
          <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
       </div>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.10" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

here is my app.js script

```
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
 var gems = [
   { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95, canPurchase: true},
   { name: 'Bloodstone', price: 5.95, canPurchase: true},
   { name: 'Zircon', price: 3.95, canPurchase: true},
 ];
 app.controller('StoreController', function(){
  this.products = gems; 
 });
})();
```

Basically i only want the 'add to cart' button to show when the object 'canPurchase' is set to true.
right now the only way i can get the button to show is by doing this:

```
     <button ng-show="!store.product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
```

it is as if the value under canPurchase doesn't do anything wither it is set to true or false.
please help me with understanding this and why it is not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  use

```
 <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
```

Not `store.product.canPurchase` as you currently have inside the `ng-repeat`. I'm pretty sure it's just that. If you don't reference the individual product item, the expression is not valid.

Verified that changing this works in this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/Lw2pxchr/)

Comment: No worries - it's nice to get one that's just a typo - for extra karma points, you can mark it as the accepted answer.